# Unable to run .NET Core 7 with Identity Server on IIS

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I've created with Visual Studio 2022 a new project .Net Core 7 + Angular with in-app authentication (identity server). Running the app locally works with no problems. I deployed it to a hosting platform and I get

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=<ip address>,1433;Initial Catalog=<dbName>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Trust Server Certificate=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "hehn_solutions": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I can't seem to find any solution for this. Can anyone help?

Update: My Program.cs looks like this (it's the unmodified one that came with "New Project")

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Add services to the container.
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    
    builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    
    builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
    
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    app.MapRazorPages();
    
    app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    
    app.Run();
```

Comment: Do you have ASP.NET Core hosting bundle for Windows installed on that machine where you are hosting this?

Comment: @AnkushJain It's a paid hosting and I don't have access to the machine, but if I create a new project without authentication, everything works just fine, so it's not the core part that's the problem. I believe it's the identity that's creating this issue.

Comment: What does your program or startup class look like?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I added the code from Program.cs. It's simply the one that came from creating the new project.

Comment: From the exception it says, ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync, I would suspect that the application behind IIS, can't ready your IdentityServer? can you confirm that? what does the application logs say?

Comment: I don't any other logs available. @ToreNestenius, all I did was to create a new Core 7 + Angular project and hit publish to my IIS hosting platform

Comment: First, Visual Studio 2019 and .Net Core 7 don't match that well I think, second I would start with a Hello World ASP.NET Core MVC application, and make sure it runs on IIS, before you try to get this application running.

Comment: If I create a new Core + angular application without in-app authentication everything works with no issue.

Comment: you can run it without iis using dotnet tool
 cmd: dotnet run

Comment: But locally it works with no issues. On my machine everything works. I have a windows web hosting that I paid on which this issue is present. I only have access to cPanel and nothing more.

Comment: I've just created a new Core 7 + Razor Pages app and published. Outcome? - works just fine. So there's a problem with the Core 7 + angular template which for me is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider does not have .Net7 installed(not likely since the razor app worked), or an updated Angular framework that supports .Net7.

The key to the new .Net targets is not requiring the newest version.

.Net 6 was a game changer(merging core and framework) and should be the minimum target unless Windows Framework 4.x features are required(rare, but still applicable.)

It takes time and effort to update to allow the newest framework features, and MS Razor had a major head start (each accepted change from 6 was propagated to the Razor team as soon as accepted for updating with validation concurrent to .Net7 RC.)

Microsoft changed some part of the authentication system, and Angular has not caught up yet,either on the installed version or in their source files.